# Issue in accessing the titleLabel of a group of buttons from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have a group of buttons inside a view, i add each group of buttons to an array according to their id, the problem is when i want to print the titleLabel of a one group Xcode gives an exception(Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aa08c0'
), here's my code

```
-(NSMutableArray*)findButtonsSection:(UIButton *)buton{
[self initialzeSectionsarray];//initializes and allocates all the arrays below.


int tag=buton.tag;

for (UIButton* bton in self.view.subviews) {
    switch (tag) {
        case 0:
            if (bton.tag==0) 
            {
                //array: it's an array holds another arrays
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];

                for (UIButton* btton in sec_0) {
          //it give me the exception when i tried to print out the buttons titles
                 NSLog(@"Buttons titles are%@",btton.titleLabel.text);
                }

            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (bton.tag==1) {
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (bton.tag==2) {
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (bton.tag==3) {
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];

            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (bton.tag==4) {
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];

            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if(bton.tag==5){
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if (bton.tag==6) {
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];

            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if(bton.tag==7){
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if(bton.tag==8){
                [[array objectAtIndex:tag]addObject:bton];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

return [array objectAtIndex:tag];
}
```

Comment: You should post the code where you fill `sec_0`. Despite what you think, it doesn't have `UIButton`s in it; it has `UIImageView`s.

Comment: You mean that posted code? You don't fill `sec_0` anywhere there. It's only referenced once, when you're enumerating it.

Comment: [array objectAtIndex:tag]---> it returns sec_0[]

Comment: I see. Okay, are you sure `self.view` _only_ has UIButtons as subviews? If it has any other kind of subview (like a UIImageView?), this code will crash.

Comment: No, it only contains UIButtons

Comment: Well, somehow a UIImageView is creeping into that array. Either you're adding one by accident, or what was once a UIButton was released and replaced with a UIImageView by the runtime. Try `NSlog(@"%@", [bton class]);` right before you switch on `tag`.

Comment: it prints some UIImageView although i does have only UIButtons I'm my view!

Comment: i used [btton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] to interact only with UIButtons, although  i have nothing but UIButtons in my view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default tag for any view is zero. So, if self.view has views that are not buttons, your code will crash. try to change the tag to be non-zero, and make sure that the view in self.view.subviews is member of UIButton class, like this: 
`if([button isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
   //Do what you want to do
}`